# Exception when testing CursorPaginator

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-8

I am running to an issue where the following code fails in testing only, while behaving correctly in the browser.

The code should provide a `CursorPaginator` for an Eloquent collection and return it as JSON.

**Test Code:**

```
public function testMoreNotesAreReturnedIfRequested()
{
    $item = Item::factory()->has(Entry::factory()->for($this->user)->count(6))->create();

    // Get page one of paginator, and request page 2 using the URL it returns
    $response = $this->actingAs($this->user)->json('get',"/items/{$item->id}/notes/more");
    $next = $this->actingas($this->user)->json('get',$response->decodeResponseJson()['next_page_url']);

    $next->assertJson(fn (AssertableJson $json) => $json
        ->has('data')
        ->has('paginator'));
}
```

The above fails with the following exception:

> Only arrays and objects are supported when cursor paginating items.

I have confirmed that there are 6 entries created in line 1, and that they all have different millisecond creation times as suggested when googling the problem.

Any ideas?

**Controller Code:**

```
return $item->entries()
            ->latest()
            ->with(['content','user'])
            ->cursorPaginate(5)
            ->withPath("/items/$item->id/notes/more")
            ->through( static function ($item) use ($request) {
                $item->setAttribute('can_edit',$request->user()->can('update',$item->content));
                $item->setAttribute('can_delete',$request->user()->can('delete',$item->content));
                return $item;
            });
```

**Edit** - the test fails every time, whereas the browser only fails when the number of items in the collection is 6, 7, 16 or 17.  I am now even more confused.

Comment: Read the _red box_ in [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#cursor-pagination), I think it is not a bug, it is you not using an `order by`.... Read the documentation so you don't waste time and energy trying to solve this issues that could kill your mental health.

Comment: @matiaslauriti is ‘latest()’ not an alias for ‘orderBy(“created_at”,”desc”)’ ?

Comment: It is, but if I am not confused you should be using `id` and not `created_at`. Either way, did you try manually writting `->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')` and see if that works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be caused by using `latest()` for ordering.  The problem was resolved by changing to

```
->orderBy('id','desc')
```

Related issues that people are having seem to suggest there is a problem with the precision of datestamps (in my case MariaDB providing 6 decimal places after the second).  See [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/37629) and [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/cursor-pagination-on-eloquent-models?page=1&replyId=717357).

I wonder if this is a bug in CursorPaginator.